# position navbar elements relative in a div

Tags: html, css

I want to have a nav bar in a div like this

[image]

I have an image in the middle of the div and I want to write the css so that my nav elements ( home, about... ) have a relative margin and are not in the image.

html

```
<div class="nav">
  <img id="diamond" src="{% static "blog/img/Diamond.png" %}">
  <a id="nav_left" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>               
  <a id="nav_left" href="{% url 'guides' %}">Guides</a>                                        
  <a id="nav_right" href="{% url 'stream' %}">Stream</a>                                       
  <a id="nav_right" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>                                         
</div>
```

current css

```
.nav {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom 0px;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 5px;
}

#nav_left {
  float: left;
  color: black;
}

#nav_right {
  float: right;
  color: black;
}

#diamond {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you use `flexbox` on your project? If so, that might be the route you wanna take. Also, you should use classes and not ids for `nav_left` and `nav_right`. Having multiple ids with the same name is invalid and thats what classes are for anyways.

Comment: Why not just change the HTML order...there's nothing special about it stopping you?

Comment: @Don'tclickonmyprofile I made you a fiddle as an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/htrwvuat/). You can see the css is very minimal to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: @zgood thank you very much for the effort :D I will check flexbox out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the source order would be the simplest method...then `inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle`.

```css
.nav {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom 0px;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#diamond {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.nav a,
.nav img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

  <a class="nav_left" href="#">Home</a> 
  <a class="nav_left" href="#">Guides</a> 
  <img id="diamond" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-5.jpg" />
  <a class="nav_right" href="#">Stream</a> 
  <a class="nav_right" href="#">About</a> 
</div>
```

`flexbox` has been mentioned and it would be possible to retain the original order of the question but the internal order would require some re-jigging.

```css
.nav {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom 0px;
  height: 20vh;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav a {
  order: 3
}
.nav a:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: -1
}
.nav a:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 1
}
#diamond {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img id="diamond" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-5.jpg" />
  <a class="nav_left" href="#">Home</a> 
  <a class="nav_left" href="#">Guides</a> 
  <a class="nav_right" href="#">Stream</a> 
  <a class="nav_right" href="#">About</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding/suggesting @media queries to your answer, this is simple indeed but it's funky looking when reducing screen sizes and I bet the OP will hit this problem very fast

Comment: That's a **whole** other discussion...not really relevant to the issue at hand.